# Mybatis insert into ... select from ... return primary keys

Tags: mybatis

Code like this:

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO entries2 (col1, col2, col3, col4...) SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4... FROM ${tableName}")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyColumn = "id")

int [] importEntries(String tableName);
```

How to return primary key ID？Thx.

Comment: If you expect multiple generated keys to be returned from that method, it won't work because JDBC does not support it. You can 1) execute another SELECT after that INSERT ... SELECT to get id values or 2) execute the SELECT part first to get a list of object and INSERT them afterwards (the generated keys will be set to each instance of the list). This [test](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-3/tree/master/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/keygen) shows how `useGeneratedKeys` works with multi-row insert (note that some drivers like mssql-jdbc does not support it).

Comment: Tks， This method can solve my problem, but there will be extra steps（`SELECT`-->`INSERT`)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this with single step.